# Is it safe to access (not modify) a Swift Dictionary from multiple threads?

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm quite certain it's not safe to *modify* a Swift `Dictionary` from multiple threads, but is it safe to access one? I'm using `pthread_rwlock` to create a lock allowing a single writer and multiple readers to protect a `Dictionary`. I've had no problems so far, but I've also been unable to find any information one whether it is safe to do so.

Here's what I mean by "access" a dictionary:

```
let value = dictionary[key]
```

Here's what I mean by "modify" a dictionary:

```
dictionary[key] = value
```

Comment: What do you mean by _to access one_ ?

Comment: Clarified in the post.

Comment: Seems you mean "read-access" by _access_, right? (Usually _access_ is used for both "read-access" and "write-access", so your terminology is not good for representing technical requirement.) Then practically it's safe under the current implementation of Swift Standard Library. But I have never seen any official info (Apple's doc or any articles posted by Swift Team members).

Comment: Contextually, in English, when the word "access" is contrasted with the word "modify", it always means "read access", at least in my experience. But I don't want to quibble about definitions. I think the intent of my post is now very clear. I just need to know whether this is safe to do.

Comment: I won't argue with terminology any more. As I wrote "I have never seen", which means "Just I" have never seen. Wait for some expert Swift watcher gives you some info about your main concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, I hope you know what you're doing for using `pthread_rwlock`. 
But overall, you shouldn't think in terms of threads but a higher level abstraction that you'll generally work with. You should think in terms of queues that Apple offers through GCD.

Now generally, if we're just talking about **only** *reading* from a `Collection` concurrently you should be fine. It's writing that you might have issues with.

That being said, I can't find any resources from Apple about this, but the code following does not cause any issues with the thread sanitiser in Xcode but it would if you changed the read to a write.

```swift
var dict = Dictionary<Int, String>()
(0..<100).forEach {
    dict[$0] = $0.description
}

let waiter = DispatchGroup()
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 100) {
    waiter.enter()
    let _ = dict[$0]
    waiter.leave()
}

waiter.wait()
print(dict)
```

Comment: Yes, in the end I used GCD, but in a somewhat different way. I created a `Lock` and used it to access my dictionary. You can see it [here](https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/master/Guise/Lock.swift).

Comment: Keep in mind that the barrier will wait until the queue is finished with pending tasks and during its execution, it will pause everything else, essentially "disabling" the concurrent nature of your queue for that period. This will for instance, not work with scenario where your writes depend on current state in a parallel operation.

Comment: I'm well aware, and not only is that fine, it's the behavior I want. The open source framework of which this is a part is used in a fair number of shipping applications with tens of thousands of users and there have been no issues with it.